# How do I change DB schema from dbo to another schema?

Tags: sql-server, view, sql-server-2012

I created a new view that have a lot of joins between multiple tables , under SQL Server 2012 Management.

The view was created under the name `dbo.vw_clientsTransactions` .

How can I change the DB schema from `dbo.vw_clientsTransactions` , to `CL.vw_clientsTransactions` ?

Thanks

Comment: Downvoter , next time have the dignity and state the reason for your downvote . -1 from me to you .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To change the schema of any object, use the following syntax:

```
alter schema [new_schema] transfer [old_schema].[object_name];
```

So, in your case, you'd do:

```
alter schema [CL] transfer [dbo].[vw_clientsTransactions];
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to delete this view and, on Create, specify your schema in the view name!

Comment: There are some (not-in-SSMS) tools that can move objects between schemas.

Comment: It doesn't allow me to save it under a schema , if I try to save it under `CL.vw_clientsTransactions` , I get : `Invalid identifier CL.vw_clientsTransactions` .

Comment: You can use 'sp_helptext vw_clientsTransactions' if you can't find the creation script.

Comment: You don't need to drop/recreate. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

OK , now I know how :

1.Create your view , save it as whatever name comes to mind .

2.Right click on the view : `Script View as => Create To => New Query Editor Windows` .

3.Now a window with the script for creating the view , would be presented on the screen .

4.Change the `dbo` to `CL` (in my case) , and then run the query (F5 / Execute) and you're done .

Comment: As I said, any tool would just create another view and delete the original. Make sure you delete the original to avoid confusion.

Comment: You don't need to drop/recreate. See my answer.